# Rails - Detecting keywords in a string with exact match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This one is tricky, at least for me as I am new to rails.

```
soccer = ["football pitch", "soccer", "free kick", "penalty"]

string = "Did anyone see that free kick last night, let me get my pen!!!"
```

What I want to do is search for instances of keywords but with 2 main rules:

1 - **Don't do partial matches** i.e it should not match pen with penalty, has to be a full match.

2 - **Match multiple sets of words** like "nice day" "sweet tooth" "three's a crowd" (max of 3)

This code works perfect for scenario 1:

```
def self.check_for_keyword_match?(string,keyword_array)
    string.split.any? { |word| keyword_array.include?(word) }
end

if check_for_keyword_match?(string,soccer)
    soccer.to_set.freeze
    keywords_found.push('soccer')
    # send a response saying Hey, I see you are interested in soccer.
end
```

In that example it would not match pen but it would match penalty which is perfect.

But I also want it to match 2-3 sets of keywords i.e "free kick" should match but only "free" and "kick" would match if they were written as singular keywords. Free is too broad, same with kick but "free kick" is not broad so it works much better at deciphering their interests.

I can change the format of the soccer array but the string been submitted would be from a slack post so I can't control how that is formatted. In the actual program I have 20 or so of those arrays with keywords but once I figure out how to do one, the rest I can handle.

Comment: Hint: [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union). Sort by longest to shortest to match the longest first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For manipulating strings, [Regular Expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm) are useful.

The following code should fix your issue:

```
def self.check_for_keyword_match?(string, keyword_array)
    keyword_array.any? { |word| Regexp.new('\b' + word + '\b').match(string) }
end
```

Instead of splitting `string`, go through `keyword_array` and search the entire `string` for each keyword.

The regex adds a 'word boundary' modifier `\b` so that it will only match entire words (Rule 1, if you use `include?` here, then a keyword of "pen" will match "penalty").